# postgresql can't create database

Tags: postgresql

I have a fresh centos 7, postgresql 9.6 install.

I need to create a new database, but I have this error:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.16)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE terminal.prod;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE terminal.prod;
                                ^
postgres=#
```

Any help ? thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have a `.` in an identifier in SQL. If you really, really want to make your life hard, you need to quote it: `"terminal.prod"` but I strongly recommend you find use a different name.

Comment: you check this link :https://www.guru99.com/postgresql-create-database.html to create postgresql database

Comment: thanks solved with ""